# How do I apply different normal maps in different areas inside a material?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, uv, normal-map

As the title and picture explains...

[image]

Comment: Hello :). No complex node setup is needed. Just create a different UV map for each Normal map.

Comment: Hi I appreciate the help! :) However I am afraid I still don't understand what to do, I am sorry :( Could you put it into layman's terms by chance? :)

Comment: Alright thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to do three things :).

**1.** Create a separate UV map for each texture (3 in total).
Only faces you put inside UV bounds will be used. Faces outside bounds will be ignored.

[image]

**2.** Connect a different UV map to each texture (use the UV Map node).
Set textures to *Clip*, so they don't repeat.

**3.** Combine the textures using *Mix RGB* nodes set to *Add*, fac=1.
And plug the result into a *Normal Map* node.

[image]

Comment: My Goodness! I appreciate this beautiful tutorial :) I am going to dig my teeth into it. Thank you again! I'll let you know if I have further questions XD and if not i'll let you know also :D Thanks so much! Is there anyway I can give you a good rep or something? Not sure how this site entirely works XD

Comment: Thanks again I am stuck for sure, I am not sure how to assign different uv maps for different sections for one object that is only using one material.

Comment: In regards to the first image you showed me, I don't know how to save different uv maps separate on one object, so I am unable to get to the node part. Thanks so much for the help again.

Comment: Thanks appreciate all the help :) I already have normal maps baked for each section I just need to be able to apply them individually in sections as one material, that is why I posted this, just wanted to make sure there were no misunderstandings :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111083/discussion-between-jachym-michal-and-uv-bakes-and-beyond).